# Data Validation with Indirect formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a VBA for Data Validation with indirect formula, but throws an error while running the macro. Am I missing something?

```
     With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(BD2)"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting an `INDIRECT` Validation throws an error if the `INDIRECT` does not evaluate to a proper range **at the time you create it** - if you do it manually, you get a pop-up saying "do you want to continue anyway", but in VBA it just fails.  Testing with `DisplayAlerts = False` does not seem to fix this.

The only options I can think of are to either populate BD2 with a temporary, valid, value, or to have a "Null" range included in an `IF` statement inside your `INDIRECT`, e.g. `Formula1:="=INDIRECT(IF(LEN(BD2)>0,BD2,""DropDown_Default""))"`, where `DropDown_Default` is a Named Range which contains a single blank cell.